# Capturing audio from a different source in Premiere?

Tags: premiere, video-editor, podcast

I have my 4 Shure mics connected to my Clarett which is registering as an audio device on my mac.

My video source will be my video camera connected to my computer.

I don't want to take audio from the video camera, as it won't sound professional for my podcast. I want to capture video from my Cannon Video camera, and capture audio from my Clarett.

Also, is iit possible to extract high quality audio from the project? Because I want to upload mp3 files to itunes and spotify for the audio-only version of the podcast. That's a side note that I can figure out.

I just could never figure out how to capture audio, i keep getting the error "lost connection to device."

Comment: OBS looks like it's more for live streaming. I am trying to record.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Audacity or OBS to record the sound from the microphone, then put it in the Premiere and synchronize it. OBS is not only for streaming, but you can use it to record a separate soundtrack from a microphone while having a camera connected.  Then in Premiere Pro you mute the soundtrack from the camera and leave the soundtrack from the microphone.

Comment: I think this can be achieved directly in Premiere, assuming the devices can be seen individually by his operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on a Mac: if the mics from your Clarett device appear as individual inputs in MacOS, you should be able to select them as input devices in Premiere.

You need to select the correct [audio hardware](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/preferences.html#audio_hardware_preferences) and video capture devices in Premiere's setup pages

Then do a live capture [as described here](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/capturing-digitizing.html).